# Solve a hypothetical mass-level extinction scenario

Tags: calculus, game-theory

Summary: A single, immortal alien life form that kills by touch seeks to eradicate all life on Earth as efficiently as possible. After killing a victim, he is able to sense the next human nearest to him, and begins to walk toward him at 3 mph until making contact, and thus killing him. The alien's speed increases at a rate of 1 mph per hour that he does not kill. How long can mankind hope to survive before extinction?

Additional details:
(1) The alien is invincible, immortal, doesn't require sleep, and can travel effortlessly through any terrain (including bodies of water) or blockade. 
(2) Take general population distribution into effect if possible.
(3) Consider that humans, once reasonably aware of the threat, can assume reasonable strategic patterns of behavior to avoid death (as individuals or groups). They cannot alter the speed of the alien, but might position themselves in such a way as to survive for as long as possible.

Comment: So the humans position themselves once and then never move again?

Comment: No, humans act like humans. This is a "real world" scenario, which is to say, humans don't act like hypothetical objects.

Comment: But then you're missing their speed. Also, if acting like humans includes not travelling effortlessly through any terrain, this is not a mathematical problem and would require lots of geographical data.

Comment: Agreed, the variables make it difficult. Humans not near to the alien would likely be moving at normal daily pace, while humans within vicinity of the alien would likely be moving at speed away from the alien. Typical human mobility varies from 3.1 mph to 15 mph on foot. Vehicles vary.

I might approach the problem in clusters which would repeat their patterns as the alien moves between urban centers.

Comment: In its present form, this is not a mathematical question. It's a nice idea, but you'd need to specify a precise model of the movements for it to be a mathematical problem.